# Image processing: optimization with constraints over values in a row

Tags: image-processing, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I have to solve an optimization problem over an image `M` indexed by pixel `[i, j] (0 < i < m, 0 < j < n)`. `M[i, j]` should give positive integer value.

For each `M[i, j]`, I have already a set of search space `S[i, j] = List<int>`, the size of `S[i, j]` is different for each pixel [i, j].

The function to be optimized is `f(M[i,j])` subjected to the constraint that the values of M[i, :] on a row should be the same.

I have difficulty to formulate this constraint as a cost function. Can you give me some hint?

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure you formulate the task correctly. Otherwise you can just check the equality of all the elements in row of an image, to say, the pixel in the first column: `np.all(M[i, :] == M[i, 0])`. If that is True, than your image is acceptable for your problem.

Comment: Hi Mironov, this seems to be the solution to my problem. The search space for each pixel is not very large (for example 10 integer variables per pixel) but the search space of the whole optimization problem is (it should be 10^(mxn)). I'm afraid that this approach does not guarantee a solution...